# Authenticating user/machine before downloading Edge extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge

My use-case is that we want to create a platform where developer can host there extension of all machine inside our OU on a private server. These all machines will be windows, so using the registry, we will enforce adding extension on all the machine and I did a POC and it works.

But the problem is that, the update_url for the extension has to be public. This we don't want. Before downloading the extension, user or machine should be validated. I am struggling to achieve this because edge makes call to extension hosting website without any hooks. I cannot manipulate any headers or request param to add authentication details

I went through the documentation of self hosting an extension and stackoverflow questions around this but didn't help

I am following this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-manage-extensions-webstore

Comment: Do you mean you host the extension on your private server, but you don't want all the users who have access to the server download the extension? You want only a part of the users have access to download the extension, right?

Comment: I don't want to make the endpoint public so that anyone can access it. Access to the crx file should be through proper authentication be it User or Edge

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to achieve this. You can control which extension to install in your groups by using group policies like [ExtensionInstallAllowlist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#extensioninstallallowlist), but you can't control who can access the extension endpoint if it's public.